# backspace not working during validation of numeric in firefox

Tags: javascript, backspace

Here is my code, how do I fix it? when i am using firefox the input number's field can't remove any number by backspace button

```
function validateValue(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;

    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault)
            theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

---

```
<div class="amountWrap"><span> CHf </span>
    <input min="1" max="99000" onkeypress="validateValue(event)" class="form-control input-lg input-ammount valid" id="single_amount_other" name="single_amount_other" placeholder="Andere Menge" aria-invalid="false" type="number">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex pattern to this:

```
var regex = /[0-9\b]|\./;
```